# libevent error when installing tmux_1.8 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, tmux, libevent

I want to install tmux 1.8 on my ubuntu 12.04 after

```
tar zxvf tmux-1.8.tar.gz
cd tmux_1.8
./configure
```

but here is some error infomation,

```
...
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for LIBEVENT... no
checking for library containing event_init... no
configure: error: "libevent not found"
mingchaoyan@mingchaoyan-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/tmux-1.8$ sudo apt-get install libevent
[sudo] password for mingchaoyan:   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libevent
```

I try to apt-get install libevent, but fail.
Can anyone help me how to solve this problem.
It will be greatful if you explain why.

Comment: You are compiling, so you need the `-dev` version of the package. Try installing `libevent-dev`.

Comment: thx~ you sovled my problem

Comment: As a side note , when using sudo apt-get install .. when you're not sure about the package name to install you can partially write the package name and press the TAB key twice to return all matching packages.. doing sudo apt-get install libevent then TAB twice will get you a nice list.. just try it next time you're not sure..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu, and appears to be a duplicate of this question on Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/273013/how-to-install-new-tmux-1-8-on-ubuntu-12-10-or-12-04

Answer (score 11):

When looking on the [tmux installation page](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) you can see two things mentioned.

That the tmux installation needs :

- libevent
- ncurses

Enter the following command in terminal to solve these two dependencies.

> `sudo apt-get install libevent-dev libncurses-dev pkg-config`

Then this following command will force(**f**) a reconfiguration of the gnu build system(*make* among others) to help install(**i**) new components (*libevent* and *ncurses*) and create symbolic (**s**) links to the new components.

> `autoreconf -fis`

#### If you're installing from the tarball (.tar.gz file)

All you have left to do is to configure and make with those commands.

> `./configure && make`

And `make install` for a **local** installation or `sudo make install` for a **global** installation.

#### If you decided to install from source with these commands.

> `git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/tmux/tmux-code tmux` [deprecated]
>   `git clone https://github.com/tmux/tmux.git` [newest source]
>   `cd tmux`

This command will verify if everything is there and that all dependencies are met when compiling from source.

> `sh autogen.sh`

You can then then run `./configure && make`and either`make install`or`sudo make install` like explained above.

Sources used:
 - [How to install new tmux 1.8 on Ubuntu 12.10 or 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/273013/how-to-install-new-tmux-1-8-on-ubuntu-12-10-or-12-04)
 - [tmux README file](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/README#l19)

Comment: i added an answer for two reasons. first there isnt a proper answer and second,the answer in the question' comments did not fix the problem i had on my part.. as in i was also missing ncurses.. digging more got me the answer.. and a good answer will surely help others :)

Comment: Pretty sure that you meant `./configure && make`... Not `./configure & make`. Unless you want to configure and make simultaneously, which wouldn't work.

Comment: indeed ,typo is now fixed :)